# Update d3 chart with newly inserted data in a Meteor collection after form submission

Tags: d3.js, meteor

My Meteor application is somewhat simple and displays a d3 chart generated with server calculated data stored in a newly inserted mongodb document:

- the user fills a simple form and clicks the submit button
- the server does some async work and CPU intensive calculation using the form data
- a new *Calculus* document with 2 fields (*formData* and *calculatedResult*) is inserted in a mongodb *Calculi* collection
- the SVG chart is updated with the newly calculated data

Despite [reading the Meteor parties example](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/parties/client/client.js) which makes use of d3, [this tutorial on using d3 and Meteor to generate SVG](http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41124327100/using-d3-and-meteor-to-generate-scalable-vector) and [this screencast on how to build a reactive data source](http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-build-a-reactive-data-source), I'm getting really confused! I'm getting a hard time properly understanding reactive data sources, templates and dependencies in Meteor.

I can't seem to be able to make the SVG chart updates after a new *Calculus* document is inserted.

Here's my question: what's a comprehensive, newbie-friendly way to automatically update a d3 generated SVG chart with server-calculated data received after submitting a form that inserts a document in a collection?

Comment: Do you have d3's .enter(), .transition() and .exit() functions set up properly: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Comment: Yes, D3 code worked fine before migrating to Meteor. I'm just trying to figure out how to plug a reactive datasource I think :).

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/steve/simple-d3-with-meteor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to have the user subscribe to changes in the Calculi collection (http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity), or if you're rendering in a template the user's response you can make and call an `update()` method that runs your d3 code. This will update your charts in the update portion of the d3 code.